# NUnit does not run on Vista x64 in Visual Studio 2003

Tags: nunit, 64-bit, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to run NUnit in Visual Studio 2003 on 64-bit Vista but with no success.

I have set the Debug Mode of the Project to "Program" and the Start Application to "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit.exe". The Test Project is set as the StartUp Project. All the code is in .NET 1.1. Unlike .NET 2.0 the processor architecture cannot be targeted (when a 1.1 executable is loaded on an x64 machine it is run in the WoW64 as a 32-bit process and utilises the 32-bit framework).

After I hit Debug > Start I receive the error window "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly". I am stuck and cannot get NUnit to run.

The nearest related question on stackoverflow dealt with getting NUnit to run on Vista x64 in Visual Studio **2005** "Nunit.exe cannot work on Vista 64bits if x86 build (stackoverflow.com/questions/208985/nunit-exe-cannot-work-on-vista-64bits-if-x86-build).
Additionally NUnit did not install a nunit-x86.exe from the NUnit-2.4.8-net-1.1.msi image.

**My Development Environment**
Vista x64 with SP1
Visual Studio 2003 (version 7.1.3088)
.NET Framework 1.1 (version 1.1.4322 SP1)
NUint 2.4.8 (installed from NUnit-2.4.8-net-1.1.msi)

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue - and it had nothing to do with Vista x64.

I had set the Debug Mode of the main Project to "Program" and the Start Application to "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit.exe" and not the Test Project.

Even though I had set the Test Project to the StartUp Project the Debug Mode in the Test Project was still set to the default "Project" and not to the "Application". I switched the debugging configurations around; so the main Project was set to "Project" and the Test Project contained the NUnit debugging configurations.

Summary: NUnit does run on Vista x64 in Visual Studio 2003.

Answer (score 0):

IF your app is a 32-bit app, then you have to use nunit-x86.exe, it is built for testing a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system. See detail explanation here: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.4.2